# Javascript IDE for iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, ide

What is a good JavaScript IDE for iPad, I don't plan on developing applications using the Ipad, but will be good for editing on the go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use Textastic for iPad.

Textastic has syntax highlighting, a keyboard with special characters on top and, you can use WebDav, Dropbox, and (S)FTP. I am a satisfied Textastic customer.

Comment: +1 for Textastic, which I also use. This is the first good code editor I've found on iPad.

Answer (score 3):

[Cloud 9](http://c9.io/) is a good cloud-based editor.

Comment: As of Version 0.5.1, it isn't friendly for the iPad. I cannot open files nor edit them. This is probably due to the fact that it uses canvas and I doubt the ipad knows to show the keyboard when the canvas is selected.

Answer (score 1):

For javascript, you don't need Cloud 9 (which is commercial).

Personally I use jsfiddle (www.jsfiddle.net) or jsbin (www.jsbin.com).

These tools can include with a simple check frameworks such as jQuery, ExtJs, Mootools, etc.
Regards.

Answer (score -1):

Before you buy an app, fool around a bit with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) you'll notice how absolutely horrible editing on the iPad is. I'd suggest a cheap netbook instead.

Comment: @Oscar: jsfiddle is not made to build full applications.

Comment: @Zakaria the IPad is not made to edit code.

Comment: I only suggested to try using jsfiddle to get a feeling for editing on the iPad with the onscreen keyboard. I've tried editing on my iPad and the experience is absolutely horrible. Even languages like python (no curly bracers) makes you want to throw it out the window.

Comment: @Raynos: why not? With a keyboard dock you can easily test/develop some functionalities. Again: web IDEs are not made for full app development.

Comment: @Zakaria "With a keyboard dock". What the ? Why don't you use a laptop! Why would you plug a keyboard into a ipad -.-. I can buy a solid laptop for $500! And I use cloud9ide for full app development.

Comment: @Raynos: I totally agree with you. But Hussein posted a question about iPad. I have the same point of view: iPad is not for devs (apart for testing).

Comment: How did this get down voted twice? All I did was suggest trying out jsfiddle for the experience of editing code on the ipad before buying an app. You can't say bad things about apple products on so?

Comment: @Oscar, I downvoted because you are incorrect. With the right software, you can use an iPad for editing. Textastic is the perfect example.  An iPad and a keyboard is still much more than a regular laptop. Any ultrathin will cost you much more than $500.

Comment: i intend to do a good bit of development on ipad with a keyboard dock using Textastic and similar apps. No netbook (or notebook for that matter) can match the quality of the new ipad's screen.

Comment: Interesting to see how quickly things change in the world of dev. iPads are increasingly being used for coding. http://yieldthought.com/post/12239282034/swapped-my-macbook-for-an-ipad